Respect existing partitions and not create new
We have an existing database and a DACPAC-based deployment procedure to send it schema updates at deploy time.  The database has an existing partition function and existing partition schemes, and the application using the database will create new partition schemes at runtime.. Currently we see SSDT dropping the existing partitions and rebuilding the table. Column data is not lost but the application-created partition schemes are lost.
What can we do to stop SSDT from dropping existing partition schemes when we deploy the DACPAC to the existing database instance?
EDIT: We have already tried both "Ignore partition schemes" (suggested by https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18826/23463) and "Ignore partition functions" (same advanced settings area). This did not change the outcome.
EDIT 2: All these options have been tried. Here's the message from my dbas:

This is about our app where Partitions are created at runtime. Anytime we apply master dacpac to DB it recreated partition  functions and schemes dropping any partitions created at runtime.
We tried: several options like below., based on docs they are supposed to work but not working

/p:ExcludeObjectType=PartitionSchemes
/p:ExcludeObjectType=PartitionFunctions 
/p:IgnoreObjectPlacementOnPartitionScheme=true 
/p:IgnorePartitionSchemes=true 
/p:IgnoreTablePartitionOptions=true 
/p:DoNotDropObjectType=PartitionSchemes  
/p:DoNotDropObjectType=PartitionFunctions 


If you could provide a worked example with code or concrete details it might help to orient people to your question, which is currently somewhat hard to follow.

@Ross there are two more options "Ignore table placement on file groups/partitions" or something like that - try disabling them too.

They have been tried already. Question updated with additional info from DBAs.

Add sqlpackage version to your question and check if there is an update available. We do have partiitoned tables in many DBs and all of those projects are deployed via sqlpackage automatically. The partition issue was resolved long time ago. I'll take a look at specific number of sqlpackage arguments but I don't think there is something more for partitions.

@RossPresser /p:IgnoreIndexOptions=true /p:IgnoreTableOptions=true

@IVNSTN this appears to be the necessary magic! please enter as an Answer and I'll accept it.

Additional magic is needed to leave partitions alone:
/p:IgnoreIndexOptions=true /p:IgnoreTableOptions=true
